# set bitmap to background of ImageView with imageView.setImageBitmap method

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView`. I am using `imageView.setImageBitmap` to set my image as background to `ImageView`. But it sets my image to `ImageView`'s source (i.e. `android:src`) , but it doesn't set my image to `ImageView`'s background (i.e. `android:background`).

When I use `imageView.setImageBitmap`, it looks like as if I used `imageView.setImageResource` not `imageView.setBackgroundResource`.

How can I handle this if I want to set my image to background using `imageView.setImageBitmap`. I know by I can do this by making custom `ImageView`. But is it possible without custom `ImageView`? If its possible, please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I have tested and it's done

I think you are getting Bitmap

So you have to convert Bitmap to BitmapDrawable

like

```
  BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap)
```

then just set bitmap with below function

```
  imageView.setBackground(ob);
```

by this way you can do it..

Comment: @Sandeep, that's not true. It's just the constructor there that is deprecated.  There is however a constructor available as `BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap)`

Comment: I got "Call requires API level 16 (currently min is 14)"

Comment: Im having the same issue I cant set it to the background. It fills up my whole android screen but does not go to the background. Being stuck for many days on this. Can someone check my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439490/upload-image-and-set-it-as-background-android/29441256?noredirect=1#comment47057907_29441256

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable() is depecated. Use setBackground()

Answer (score 11):

Try following code to set your own bitmap as background.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ...;
ImageView imageView = ...;
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
imageView.setBackground(drawable);
```

Answer (score 5):

try this..

Create drawable using bitmap & use setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d) method for imageview.

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);

imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please Use the following line to set image background.

```
imageview.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uporder));
```

Here uporder is an image resource present in your drawablefolder.

Comment: getDrawable has been deprecated.  :(

Comment: He ask about bitmap and you answered on Drawable. It's not helpful at all.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use this because is not deprecated and it works in the lowers versions of android.

```
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bitmap;
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 1):

call setBackgroundDrawable withe BitmapDrawable param

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable`is deprecated now.. :(

Comment: @ Hameno , It Matters actually. android guys give other better options to deprecated methods.